# Event tracking not working on Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I've tried everything to try to get some simple event tracking to work to no avail. Here's the code. I'm using Universal Analytics.

```
 <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx', 'thissite.net');
          ga('send', 'pageview');


            /*Testing with this link*/

              $('.home-logo').on('click', function() {
                alert('clicked');
                ga('send', 'event', 'homelogo', 'click', 'icons');

        });
         </script>

        <!--Sample Link -->
         <a href="/portal/" class="home-logo"><img src="/images/aeportal_logo_small.png" width="95" border="0" /></a>
```

It's using AJAX and services to render content on the application, so I am not sure if something else needs to be done. I know there's a 'hit callback' function as well, but that didn't work either. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Is the alert not showing up? If so did you try putting the click handler inside of doc ready? Also if the `.home-logo` is created dynamically and after the js has run then you need to delegate the click

Comment: Thanks, actually it's just part of the PHP template, so it shouldn't require delegation

Comment: Is [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) what you're looking for by any chance?...

Comment: Also, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks. No errors that I can see

Comment: @erics15 Are you checking in real time report or in normal report? It might take awhile before it gets updated in the normal reports

Comment: I actually was checking real time just to test, but nothin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to delay the page from moving on so GA can send the event.

You can do that with the `hitCallback` function and put it in a reusable function so you can add events for outbound links all over the page:

```
function trackOutboundLinks(category, action, label, url){
    ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, {'hitCallback':
       function () {
           document.location = url;
        }
     });
}

$('.home-logo').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     trackOutboundLinks("homelogo", "click", "icons", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Alternatively, you can add an `onclick` function to the link itself rather than use the `.on` function above:

```
<a href="/portal/" class="home-logo" onclick="trackOutboundLinks('homelogo', 'click', 'icons', '/portal/'); return false;"><img src="/images/aeportal_logo_small.png" width="95" border="0" /></a>
```

Also, you can use the [Google Analytics Debugger extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to check if the events are fired rather than staring at real-time.

[Google Analytics Reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)

Comment: Still no dice, i don't get it. I actually put alerts on both the after the click and the trackOutboundLinks function executes. Both alerts pop up, but the second comes and goes quickly. Not sure if it's able to ping the GA server in time, that's really the only thing I can think of at this point :/.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be working now. I marked your answer as correct :)